# Control the Size of TextField in UIKit Application

Tags: ios

I am using the following to add a UITextField to a UIStackView. The main issue is the UITextField is expanding to take the complete height. What am I doing wrong? I want UITextField to be of 44 or 60 points height.

```
   lazy var nameTextField: UITextField = {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textfield.placeholder = "Budget name"
        textfield.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
        textfield.leftViewMode = .always
        textfield.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        return textfield
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        setupUI()
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.alignment = .leading
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stackView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 20, bottom: 20, trailing: 20)
        
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(nameTextField)
        
        // add constraints on nameTextField
        nameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        
        
        // add constraints stackview
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
       
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UIStackView` **arranges** its subviews (`.addArrangedSubview()`).

So, you are telling auto-layout to:

- make the text field 60-points tall

  - **AND**
- make the text field as tall as the stack view

In this case, the stack view wins.

---

**Edit** - *for clarification...*

When you ran your app, you should have seen a bunch of auto-layout error / warning messages. That tells you that you have assigned conflicting constraints.

If you want the text field height to use the `.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)` that you've assigned, you have a few options...

1 - Don't embed it in a stack view.

2 - Don't assign a height to the stack view (either directly or with top & bottom constraints).

3 - add additional `arrangedSubviews` to the stack view.

So, if you make only this change to your code:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(nameTextField)

// comment out this line
//stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

you'll get this:

[image]

If you leave that line in, and add a yellow-background `UILabel` as another arranged subview:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(nameTextField)

// leave this un-commented
stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

let label = UILabel()
label.text = "The Label"
label.backgroundColor = .yellow

label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
```

you'll get this:

[image]

because you gave the text field an explicit Height constraint, so the label height "stretches."

Or, if you add the label **and** omit the stack view's bottom anchor:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(nameTextField)

// comment out this line
//stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "The Label"
label.backgroundColor = .yellow

label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
```

you'll get this:

[image]

because you gave the text field an explicit Height constraint, and let the label use its `Intrinsic Content Size`.

Comment: So solution is to not use addArrangedSubView?

Comment: But I am also putting constraints on TextField height but those constraints have no effect.

Comment: @johndoe - see the **Edit** to my answer.